# How to insert a line break in specific anchor in JS?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to insert a break after the second anchor via JavaScript?

```
<a title="1" href="#">Link 1</a>
<span>|</span> 
<a title="2" href="#">Link 2</a>
<span>|</span> 
<a title="3" href="#">Link 3</a>
<span>|</span> 
<a title="4" href="#">Link 4</a>
<span>|</span> 
<div>This is something else blahblah</div>
```

I try to append %0D%0A to an anchore but there's no class/id. The HTML isn't from me so I was looking for a way to select a specific element.

Comment: Of course. What have you tried?

Comment: Please add you code to your question and not in a comment. PS it's easier to use <br/>

Comment: Thanks for @Guilherme jumping out to help (and being nice.)

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn I had my code in the question since day one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a nice, built in function for this: after(), at http://api.jquery.com/after/

In your case, you will probably want a selector like this:

```
$('#yourAnchorId').after('<br/>');
```

The code examples from the link given above also show how to load jQuery if that is new to you.

Comment: the HTML isn't from me, so there's no id nor class. It's just hanging out there.

Comment: You can use different selectors with jquery. For an exemple, $('title=2') will get the second anchor

Comment: @YogaPanda Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Why are you using jQuery??

Comment: @Ele I don't understand your question. In my answer I suggested YogaPanda to use it, because it is easier for him to do such things.

Comment: Thank you for being the first one helping me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
var lineBreak = document.createElement('br');
var target = document.querySelector('a[title="3"]');

document.body.querySelector('#AnchorParent').insertBefore (lineBreak, target);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `insertAdjacentElement`:

```js
document.querySelector('[title="2"]').insertAdjacentElement('afterend', document.createElement('br'))
```

```html
<a title="1" href="#">Link 1</a>
<span>|</span> 
<a title="2" href="#">Link 2</a>
<span>|</span> 
<a title="3" href="#">Link 3</a>
<span>|</span> 
<a title="4" href="#">Link 4</a>
<span>|</span> 
<div>This is something else blahblah</div>
```

## Resource

- [`Element.insertAdjacentElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)

  > The insertAdjacentElement() method inserts a given element node at a given position relative to the element it is invoked upon.
  >
  > **position param**
  >
  > A DOMString representing the position relative to the targetElement; must >match (case-insensitively) one of the following strings:
  >
  > - 'beforebegin': Before the element itself.
  > - 'afterbegin': Just inside the element, before its first child.
  > - 'beforeend': Just inside the element, after its last child.
  > - 'afterend': After the element itself.